# Connected to Wi-Fi but Internet not working

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, internet

Internet was working fine on my MacBook Pro until this morning and now suddenly stopped working.

I'm able to establish a connection with the Wi-Fi network but I can't access Internet or even ping the router.

I have tried setting up manual IP address, tried different values for DNS including 8.8.8.8, restarted modem and the laptop few times. I have also removed all the unused networks from the advance network settings and also rejoined my Wi-Fi network.

Other devices connected to the modem are working fine. I tried to connect my MacBook to my iPhone hotspot but still no luck. I can connect but internet does not work.

Comment: When you say: "I'm able to establish a connection with the Wi-Fi network but I can't access Internet or even ping the router." if you are not able to ping the router how can you say that you have established a connection?